# Get the latest CTL or list of trusted root certificates

Tags: certificate, windows-update

I need to implement a service that does not start because the certificate cannot be validated. This certificate have a root ca that was recently created, so my windows 7 machines does not trust in this ca. My machines does not have internet access and can't download from windows update the list of trusted root certificates (CTL)

```
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265983.aspx
```

In this technet article say that this CTL can be downloaded from Microsoft download center but I have searched and I just found a KB of 2013 that contains the CTL.

My question is ¿where I can find the latest version of this list of trusted certificated?

> Note:
>   I cant add a certificate manually or via script

Comment: The Technet article explains several methods you can use to download the certificates. Have you read the _complete_ article?

Comment: yes I have readed it and  have understand that there are two methods to update via a server os a package created with iexpress that contains the list of valid certificates or a web server.

Comment: what i need is one of those iexpress package that contains the list, that is supposedly in Microsoft downloads

Comment: What if you just push the Root CA used to generate the server certificate to the Win7 client? This should be enough to validate the service

Comment: by adding the certificate manually works fine but i can't do this because the company that I am working requires that the CTL must be updated by this microsoft update

Answer (score 4):

I found the instructions at the [bottom of this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2813430/an-update-is-available-that-enables-administrators-to-update-trusted-and-disallowed-ctls-in-disconnected-environments-in-windows) to be useful.

Specifically, running

```
    CertUtil –generateSSTFromWU Rootstore.sst
```

Gave me a file with all the needed Certs. I then was able to transfer that `Rootstore.sst` file to another machine, open the file and install the desired certs from it.

When opening the file in Certmgr I'm able to see all the certs, I can then add any that I need (to install Visual Studio 2015 on an offline Windows 7 box, I needed the "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010" and "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011") by double clicking to open them, then clicking the install button. However, when I select "Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate" it didn't put these in the trusted root. Instead I had to manually pick the certificate store and then select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

Comment: Hi, this is quite good except for the fact once I've the file... How can I import all the certificates? I mean, my .sst file has 369 certificates, I could do it manually, but... Well, you get my point ;-) Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The article at https://netflex.nl/automatische-ca-root-updates-op-windows/ suggests that you download the root certificates with rootsupd.exe, available at http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/rootsupd.exe.
I'm surprised though that the exe is **not signed**.
Use at your own risk.

Comment: 404 error on the EXE

Comment: The `rootsupd.exe` (and the `updroots.exe` inside of it) are outdated and should not be used. In fact, they break the "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority" root certificate on modern systems (at least Windows 10 1803+).

Answer (score 2):

Our team actually just developed a tool to automatically update the root certificates on Windows 10, Server 2012/2016/2019.

It's free.

https://asher.tools/root-certificate-updater